# do catechol and quinol give iodoform test just like resorcinol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

do catechol and quinol give iodoform test just like resorcinol?
as ..in case of resorcinol we do have a active methyl after tautomerization which is highly acidic could some kind of mechanism be applicable for para hydroxy phenol and ortho hydroxy phenol

Answer (score 4):

No they do not as they cannot undergo the retro-aldol to give an open chain compound as resorcinol does - see scheme below

[image]

Image sourced from  [here](https://www.chemzipper.com/2020/01/how-can-explain-resorcinol-13.html)  - (and yes the open chain product responsible for the positive iodoform test is missing a double bond)